# How to get seeds in Stardew valley?

Tags: stardew-valley

I have been playing the game for an hour and the only seeds I got were from the Mayor. How to get more seeds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the start of the game, the two ideal places to obtain seeds are via [Pierre's General Store](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Pierre%27s_General_Store) or [JojaMart](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/JojaMart). You can also occasionally find [mixed seeds](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Mixed_Seeds) 
by cutting weeds.

Later in the game, additional ways to obtain seeds is available, such as through the [Seed Maker](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Seed_Maker).

Comment: Just as a note, Seeds from Joja are usually a bit more expensive than seeds from Pierre's (unless you destroy the community centre and go the Joja route then they are the same). However Joja Mart has much better availability than Pierre's (Longer store hours, and the cashier doesn't wander around and refuse to sell to you if you show up 10 min late).

Comment: @Malco I do believe your comment could be included in the answer. It is really helpful.